# Order lines by number of occurrences

Tags: list, shell, sh

Given a list with one element per line (with occasionally some blank lines), e.g.:

```
22008
6881
6881
22008

6881
22008
22008
6881

56515
8080
8080
56515

22008
45682
45682
22008
```

I would like to get as output a list with unique items sorted by number of occurrences:

```
22008 - 6
6881 - 4
8080 - 2
45682 - 2
56515 - 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` and `sort`. cnt uses your numbers in column 1 `$1` as an index. Adds `++` 1 to value of array index $1 on each row. Pipe (`|`) to `sort`. `sort` column 2 (`-k2`) in reverse (`-r`)

```
awk '/[0-9]/ {cnt[$1]++}END{for(k in cnt) print k,"- " cnt[k]}' file.txt |sort -rk2
```

if you remove the `/[0-9]/` you'll also get the number of blank lines as a bonus :).

If you want, you can use `/^[0-9]+/` to do a full match; but, as we use `$0` for counting it doesn't really matter here.

Comment: If you have GNU awk, you can use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"; for (k in cnt) ...` and you can avoid the pipe to sort -- see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning

Answer (score 2):

Numbers sorted by number of occurrences:

```
$ grep -vE '^$' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
      6 22008
      4 6881
      2 8080
      2 56515
      2 45682
```

#### How it works

- `grep -vE '^$' file`

  Remove empty lines from file
- `sort | uniq -c`

  Sort the numbers then print unique ones with a count of their occurrences.
- `sort -rn`

  Sort numerically in declining order by occurrence count.

Answer (score 1):

The `uniq` command has an option `-c` to emit the number of consecutive occurrences it finds. The solution then is to first remove blank lines and `sort` the list for input to `uniq -c`, then `sort` the output on the first field, which contains the occurrences number.

Output of `sed '/^\s*$/d' | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1nr` is

```
   6 22008
   4 6881
   2 45682
   2 56515
   2 8080
```

Note the option to `sort` at the end: `-k1nr` means sort on the first field, numerically, in reverse (i.e. descending) order.

Comment: Recent versions of busybox have `uniq`; if you can't use a recent version, then `awk` is probably your best bet (see @Vidhya G's answer).

Comment: This is a router, uniq is not available and I can't upgrade busybox (comes with the router firmware) . Thanks for the answer any ways! I really appreciate you effort.